# How do I make a new main class? There is already one made but its not its own .java file and currently does not work

Tags: java, class, browser, netbeans, program-entry-point

### I am using Lobo Browser in NetBeans 11.2 and I cant run the program because NetBeans cannot read which file has the Main class which is in the main browser file (main class of main browser code below)
I would like to get this working because I need some code that I want to steal but I would like to see how the browser runs first.

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // Detect if we are running on mac
    if (isMac()) {
      System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
      System.setProperty("dock.name", "LoboBrowser");
    }

    // Checking for stack allows us to call AccessController.doPrivileged()
    // which in turn allows us to reduce the permissions on Uno codesource
    final int stackDepth = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length;
    if (stackDepth > 11) {
      System.err.println("Stack depth (" + stackDepth + ") is too deep! Quitting as a safety precaution");
      Thread.dumpStack();
      System.exit(1);
    } else {
      privilegedLaunch(args);
    } 
}
  private static void launch(final String[] args) {
    try {
      final SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = TrustManager.makeSSLSocketFactory(ReuseManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/trustStore.certs"));
      ReuseManager.getInstance().launch(args, socketFactory);
    } catch (final Exception err) {
      final StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
      final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(swriter);
      err.printStackTrace(writer);
      writer.flush();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
              "An unexpected error occurred during application startup:\r\n" + swriter.toString(),
              "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      System.err.println(swriter.toString());
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a class definition? Also there are probably some import statements? Please create a [mre] so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to put the main method with in a class as described here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/main-method.html. I know in net beans you can tell it what class to try to run by I think right clicking the run then selecting what file to run and if its set up correctly it will run the file.